# Magento 2 Add to cart button is disabled after importing products

Tags: magento2, addtocart, frontend-error

I'm struggling with a weird problem.

I imported products with attributes and attributes set to my store successfully.
However I notice that **Add to cart** button is disabled! it's just disabled in product page, on catalog is fine. What could it be? I have multistore, don't know if that could be a reason.
Look:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: i think you not added product qty. so product qty.2) run `php bin/magento i:rei` ...

Comment: I found that might be a problem with my theme, I switched to Luma theme and Add to cart is allowed. :(